# Scheduling coursework/assignment through API

Tags: google-classroom

Is there a way to schedule assignments to be published at a later date?

Currently we can only set DRAFT or PUBLISHED state and cannot specify the publish date when creating an assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is not possible using the [API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/faq) which currently supports creating assignments only. In creating a coursework, you can only set the status to **`PUBLISHED`** and **`DRAFT`** (no delaying publish). You can submit, view, and vote on feature requests in their [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=label%3AAPI-Classroom).